# Array of doubles and heap corruption

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, memory-management

I have a function like

```
template <class Type>
myFunc(Type** arrayToBeFilled);
```

I call it like this:

```
double* array = NULL;
myFunc(&array);
```

And inside the function I do some reading and parsing numbers with strtod function:

*//Here comes file opening, getting number of lines and number of doubles in every  line*

```
...
    char *inputString = new char[LONG_STRING_SIZE]; 
    char *pNext = NULL;
   (*arrayToBeFilled) = new Type[length*rowSize];

for (int i=0; i<length; i++)
    { 
        source.getline(inputString, LONG_STRING_SIZE);
        pNext = NULL;

     for (int j=0; j<rowSize; j++)
     {
         double d = strtod(inputString, &pNext);
        (*arrayToBeFilled)[i*rowSize+j] = d;
        inputString = pNext;
        pNext = NULL;
     }
    }
```

Variable d is just for check with debugger - and it's just fine while running.
But after filling the array I try to print it (just for check)

```
for (int i=0; i<length; i++)

    {
        for (int j=0; j<rowSize; j++)
            {
                cout<<(*arrayToBeFilled)[i*rowSize+j]<<"  ";
            }
        cout<<"\n";
    }
```

And here comes bad output - other numbers, sometimes heap corruption and so. I was printing it in and out of the function - the same results. And I can't delete this array no or neither out the function  - run time errors follow me!

Comment: The code you posted looks OK - the problem is probably in the code you haven't posted. Can you post a complete example that produces the errors?

Comment: shouldn't it be i*length (as you're iterating length) + j?

Comment: @KamilKlimek: Nope. Think about `i` as the number of rows to skip over to get to the start of the current row. It follows that the number of *elements* to skip over is `i*rowSize`.

Comment: Note that you create a raw C array on the heap with `new char[LONG_STRING_SIZE]` and assign the pointer to it to `inputString`; then you modify `inputString` with an assignment from `pNext`: so, do you leak `inputString` initial array?

Comment: @Mr_C64 Yep, you are right! One problem solved.

Comment: @Mr_C64 Can you post it as an answer? Because it just fixed my problem. I use one char* with new/delete and one extra char* for strtod() calls now. And it works perfect!

Comment: @ПавелОганесян: I've edited my answer adding a note on inputString leak.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you use raw C arrays in C++? If you use **STL classes** like `std::vector` instead of raw `new[]`, your code will become cleaner, simpler to read and maintain (for example, you don't need explicit `delete[]` calls: the destructor will cleanup heap memory). In general, in modern C++ the rule is "*if you are writing new or delete, you are doing it wrong*" (with some exceptions).

Note also that with C++11 move semantics, you can simply return the `vector` instead of using output reference/pointer arguments:

```
template <typename Type>
inline std::vector<Type> myFunc()
{
    ...
}
```

Inside your function body, instead of your code

```
(*arrayToBeFilled) = new Type[length*rowSize];
```

just write:

```
std::vector<Type> arrayToBeFilled(length*rowSize);
```

and then simply `return arrayToBeFilled;` .

(Note also that `vector`'s can be nested together: you may also use `vector<vector<Type>>` to make a 2D array, but this is less efficient than a single `vector<Type>`, which more directly maps to your raw `new[]` call.)

In addition, in the code you posted you create a raw C array on the heap with `new char[LONG_STRING_SIZE]` and assign the pointer to it to `inputString`; then you modify `inputString` with an assignment from `pNext`: but in doing so, you leak the initial array whose pointer was stored in `inputString`.

Comment: 100% correct, but I tested iterations with raw arrays and vectors and with max optimisation arrays were way better. So I try to get familiar with them for perfomance.

Comment: If you are using Visual C++, did you compare performance in _release_ builds (in the debug builds there is additional machinery to detect buffer overruns, invalid iterators, etc. that is helpful for debugging but causes overhead)?

Answer (score 1):

Seems you don't have a return type

```
template <class Type>
void myFunc(Type** arrayToBeFilled);
```

and you should initialize your function

```
double array = NULL;
myFunc<double>(&array);
```

also when it comes to input, print out the values that you get, more often than not you may get something unexpected which causes the error.